# Iframe replacement in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe

I am currently working on a project in which `iframe` is used. The `iframe` works fine, but I am facing some compatibility issues.

Searched many articles and found that `iframe` has its own drawbacks. **Is there any other alternative for `iframe`?** I have been stuck on this since couple of days. Any helpful suggestions will be appreciated.

**Edit-**

Here is my workflow:

I have a main `html` page in which i have placed an `iframe` which loads different pages within itself on clicking different links in the main `html` page. Now the pages are all loading fine, but some issues are being faced, eg. `iframe` doesn't load in Firefox or IE, `iframe` sometimes take more time in loading and such..

So I'm looking for an alternative for `iframe` that i could use.

Comment: an alternative for ifram for **what** exactly? please edit your question and try to fill in more details as to what you want to do, what you tried so far and why it didn't work.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann have edited the question, let me know if more detail is needed.

Comment: @jait23 did you try removing the `iframe` altogether.. I faced somewhat similar problem and it helped me there.